# Smoothness of group action on Borel spaces

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, group-actions, ergodic-theory

While reading Robert Zimmer’s “Ergodic Theory and Semisimple Groups”, I came across the definition of smooth actions of groups on Borel spaces. Namely, if $S$ is a countably separated Borel $G$-space, the action is smooth if the quotient Borel structure on $S/G$ is countably separated.

Is this notion related to smoothness in the sense of $C^{\infty}$ maps or simply they share the same name?

Comment: I am not sure, but he definition you gave of smooth action is more close to just continuous map. Indeed there is no notion of derivability there.